# Matrix operation with data.table, incorrect specification?

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to use `dcast.data.table` with `as.matrix`, in the same way I use it with the `dcast`, but I'm failing in achieving comparable outcome. I'll appreciate any advice on this.

```
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)
data(ChickWeight)

# this returns the correct dimension:
> as.matrix(dcast(ChickWeight, weight ~ Diet, value.var = "Time")[,-1])
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
        1 2 3 4
  [1,]  1 0 0 0
  [2,]  2 3 2 1
  [3,]  1 2 0 2
      .....

# this doesn't
    > as.matrix(dcast.data.table(setDT(ChickWeight), weight ~ Diet, value.var = "Time")[,-1])
Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
     [,1]
[1,]   -1
```

Comment: Don't coerce to a matrix, just use `table`, like `setDT(ChickWeight)[, table(weight,Diet)]` or in base R: `with(ChickWeight, table(weight,Diet))`. I think there are few, if any, cases where `dcast` ought to be used with `as.matrix`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current CRAN version of `data.table`, the following is fine:

```
as.matrix(dcast.data.table(setDT(ChickWeight), weight ~ Diet, 
                      value.var = "Time")[,-1])
```